# full background and responsive

Tags: css

please see link below

as you can see there's a text on header (header is an image)
the text is: 
mail@yahoo.com (this text is a part of image)

I convert that part of header image to link with below code

```
<div id="hw"><div id="header"><img src="test.jpg" /><a href="#" id="ResponsiveLink"></a></div></div>
```

and this is #link

```
#ResponsiveLink {
    width: 267px;
height:29px;
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
margin-left:413px;
}
```

how can we make that link be responsive in other devices? for example when browser is narrow position of the a tag with `#ResponsiveLink` id changes but i want it be fixed over my text.

Comment: Unless you want to use `media-queries` to move the position of `#ResponsiveLink` per screen size, I'd suggest you cut out the header  separately, then wire up the email image around an **a** tag

Comment: my main goal is it be responsive nevermind with wich way. with seperated image how can I made it responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're currently building isn't a sustainable solution and you should definitely see other replies on how to improve your site layout.

However, if you need a temporary solution, the following CSS changes will work on your current page:

```
#header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    position: relative;
}

#ResponsiveLink {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
    display: block;
    height: 30%;
    left: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 12%;
    top: 37%;
}
```

Comment: also thanks sheric for valuable information

yes I'm new in responsive and need more trying

but could you please write me which steps I need to reach above goal but in proper way?

Comment: You will want to build your site out of a number of nested elements that have their own visual effects, rather than making a background and then laying invisible elements over it.
Depending on your skill level you may want to start learning how basic HTML layouts work from scratch. If you're simply having trouble with responsiveness, you may want to use a platform that abstracts it for you to a certain extent, like Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know, is not to put a big part of your screen as an image. On the other hand you probably don't want to cut the image into several separate images. So, I suggest using [CSS Sprit](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

After separating the image, you can put the parts beside each other using float, clear, and percentage widths, or use a framework like bootstrap.

If you still want to use the image as a whole header, in a single HTML tag which don't recommend at all, using percentage top for your #ResponsiveLink would work. You should just add `width: 100%` to all its parents: header, hw, and wrapper.

---

Following the comments:

```
#ResponsiveLink {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 58%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 7%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
}
```

This will fix the problem because of the difference between percentages of position and margin, top percentage is calculated using first absolute parent's height but margin and padding percentages are calculated using parent's width. There's still a problem caused by the max width which you can fix adding a wrapper inside your `#head` with a width of 100% and no max width.

The other try of using floats and separated images have too many problems to write here, sorry.

Comment: > After separating the image, you can put the parts beside each other using float, clear, and percentage widths

and do you mean in small screen I put this three part under each other not in a horizontal line beside each other?
..........................
also I test margin-top in percentage but the link position changes with changing browser width.

Comment: also I worked with css sprite but in pixel, i dont know how can I use it in responsive

Comment: Using float, you can out those parts in a horizontal line if you assign a suitable width.

Making a page responsive, can be done in many ways, including using percentages instead of pixels but you should be careful about that. The way I recommend is to use [bootstrap](http://http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: thanks, yes i need to learn bootstrap but at this time I have short time, so please help do it Temporary. also i test this #ResponsiveLink
{
    width: 267px;
 background:red;
 height:10%;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 margin-left:60%;
 width:25%;
 
 
}   it's better now but the link position changes by resizing browser

Comment: Can you put it on jsfiddle? or update your website, so I can debug it?